# openlayers use svg as layers can't work on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, openlayers

When i use an SVG as layer, i have set `imageSize` but it doesn't work on IE11.But on IE10,it works.

openlayers version: 4.6.5.

here is my demo.

https://lucas0819.github.io/

here is my code.

```
var imgWidth = 1132;
var imgHeight = 804;
var center = [0, 0];
var extent = [-566000, -402000, 566000, 402000];
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 7
    }),
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg',
                imageSize: [imgWidth, imgHeight],
                imageExtent: extent
            })
        })
    ]
});


<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (including a sample .svg file)

Comment: I have edited my issue, and it still works on IE10, doesn't work on IE11

Comment: Google search for "svg not displaying in ie11" suggests it's a browser issue affecting much more than openlayers.  Adding

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>`

then adding the polyfill used in the openlayers examples and commenting out the imageSize setting did result in some incomplete output.  (The imageSize  in your example also produced inconsistent results in Chrome and Edge but consistent without it).

Answer (score 1):

It's because on IE11, it can't get image's height when create an element by `new Image();`
To get image's height i rewrite function `defaultImageLoadFunction` in options:

```
imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
  image.getImage().src = src;
  image.getImage().width = imgWidth;
  image.getImage().height = imgHeight;
}
```